# Cannot implicitly convert to type string to System.Net.Mail.MailAddress

Tags: type-conversion, system.net.mail

I am working on an inventory application system that is updating tracking forms, and I recently converted from System.Web.Mail to System.Net.Mail.

However in regards to an exception if-else statement I made that handles when an item transfer fails, I get a:

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection"
error for the following code block:

```
else //If the Item Transfer Fails
{
   _formToUpdate.WorkFlowStep = "d";
   _formToUpdate.InventoryCertifier_Initials = dbcontext.Custodies.Where(x => x.Custody_eraider == User.Identity.Name.ToLower()
   _formToUpdate.InventoryCertifierInitials_DtTm = DateTime.Now;
   _formToUpdate.IsFormLockedforEditing = true;

//The notification lists are different in both cases.
NotificationEmail.To = dbcontext.Custodies.Where(x => x.Custody_eraider ==
_formToUpdate.TransferFrom_Sign).Single().Custody_Email + ","
 + dbcontext.Custodies.Where(x => x.Custody_eraider == _formToUpdate.TransferTo_Sign).
Single().Custody_Email + "," + dbcontext.Custodies.Where(x => x.Custody_eraider ==
_formToUpdate.Form_Approv_Reject_By).Single().Custody_Email + ","
+ dbContext.Custodies.Where(x => x.Custody_eraider == _formToUpdate.InventoryCertifier_
Initials).Single().Custody_Email;
}
```

The error just occurs in the portion of the code that starts with NotificationEmail.To = ...

I'm just not too sure how to go about revising that statement properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I need to provide more detailed info, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I have already declared NotificationEmail as:
var NotificationEmail = new MailMessage();

I didn't put that portion of the code in though because there is about 100-120 lines below that which are unapplicable to the problem I'm having. Just wanted to clarify that NotificationEmail was declared though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you cannot convert a string to a `MailAddressCollection`.

In the `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` class, [the `To` property is a MailAddressCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to.aspx), not a string as it was in `System.Web.Mail.MailMessage`.

You'll need to add the email address(es) to that collection. The `MailAddressCollection` has an `Add` method that looks like it takes a string in the same format as before, so your code should probably look like:

```
NotificationEmail.To.Add(/* your expression here */);
```

Comment: Alright, Thanks! That solved my problem, and helped me clear a bunch of other similar errors in other files I had too.